# CLIPS match first field of a pattern

Tags: clips

I am trying to retract all facts of form:

```
(<something> task-error)
```

To do this I wrote the rule:

```
(defrule retract-task-error "retract task error"
         (declare (salience -1000))
         ?f <- (?n task-error)
         =>
         (retract ?f)
)
```

But it does not work with error:

```
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for the first field of a pattern.
```

Is it ever possible to accomplish this task with CLIPS or do I need a code rearrangement to avoid matching first fields of facts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first field of a pattern must be a symbol. The simplest solution would probably be adding a common symbol (such as task) to the beginning of all facts and patterns which can contain task-error:

```
(defrule retract-task-error "retract task error"
         (declare (salience -1000))
         ?f <- (task ?n task-error)
         =>
         (retract ?f)
)
```